# Concurrency in Play 2.1 or above

Tags: scala, playframework, executioncontext

I've read a few tutorials on how to deal with concurrency in Play and found some examples:

**Asynchronous Job**

```
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, future}

def sendEmailAsync(from: String, to: String, subject: String, body: String) = {
  import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global // in scala.concurrent

  future {
    EmailHelper.sendEmail(from, to, subject, body)
  }
}
```

**Scheduled Job**

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.{Akka, Execution}

def sendEmailOnSchedule(from: String, to: String, subject: String, body: String) = {
  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  import Execution.Implicits.defaultContext // in play.api.libs.concurrent

  Akka.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10 seconds) {
    EmailHelper.sendEmail(from, to, subject, body)
  }
}
```

Well, I'm a bit confused... the first example uses `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` while the second example uses `play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext`. Why? Could someone explain me what is going on behind the scene?

Comment: The `ExecutingContext` was something like java's ExecutorService(Thread Pool), you can even create it yourself if you like. For example, play-slick module use a separated context to execution db operations.  https://github.com/freekh/play-slick/blob/master/src/main/scala/play/api/db/slick/SlickExecutionContext.scala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala uses an `ExecutionContext` for some asynchronous things (Futures, Promises). An ExecutionContext can be thought of like a Thread Pool, in which `Runnables` can be submitted to be run on one of the threads. (It isn't necessarily always a thread pool, but it tends to be).

The way the ExecutionContext is used is usually to pass it in as an `implicit` argument to the function that would use it. You'll often see method signatures like this:

```
def doAsyncThings(args: Args)(implicit exc: ExecutionContext): Future[Result]
```

The "doAsyncThings" method will use the implicit `exc` that gets passed in to put work onto a separate thread.

To answer your question, the `Implicits` imports from the two examples are implicit ExecutionContext instances, which are needed to call the `future` and `scheduleOnce` methods. For exploratory purposes, it doesn't matter which one you use. The `global` one from the scala library contains (iirc) a thread pool with 8 or so threads. I would guess that the play one is similar. Unless you are being extra-careful about which threads do what work, the choice should not affect you.

Answer (score -2):

I would guess the difference comes from "10 seconds". the ability to literally name times like is not built into the language. "seconds" is implicitly converted to DurationInt.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the dispatcher, it comes from the `scala.concurrent.duration._` import.